# Nginx allow specific ip4 addresses

Tags: nginx, routes, webserver

I want to allow only specific client ip4 addresses to reach my site.
But I can see on access log only the external ip address not the real ip4 address of client.

**What I did tried:**

```
server {                                                                              
    server_name test.sample.com;                             
                                                                                      
  location / {                                                                        
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                     
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                 
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                 
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;                                               
        set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;                                                   
        #proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;                                                  
        # my specific ip4 adresses to allow                                                           
        allow 192.XXX.XXX; 
        allow 192.XXX.XXX;                                            
        deny all;                                                                     
                                                                                      
   }                                                                                  
                                                                                      
    root /usr/share/nginx/test;                                                       
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app-server-error.log notice;                             
    index demo-index.html index.html;                                                 
    expires -1;                                                                       
                                                                                      
                                                                                      
    sub_filter_once off;                                                              
    sub_filter 'server_hostname' '$hostname';                                         
    sub_filter 'server_address'  '$server_addr:$server_port';                         
    sub_filter 'server_url'      '$request_uri';                                      
    sub_filter 'remote_addr'     '$remote_addr:$remote_port';                         
    sub_filter 'server_date'     '$time_local';                                       
    sub_filter 'client_browser'  '$http_user_agent';                                  
    sub_filter 'request_id'      '$request_id';                                       
    sub_filter 'nginx_version'   '$nginx_version';                                    
    sub_filter 'document_root'   '$document_root';                                    
    sub_filter 'proxied_for_ip'  '$http_x_forwarded_for';                             
}
```

Nothing of them works. When I display access log:

```
87.xx.xxx.xxx - - [20/Oct/2020:22:29:15 +0000] "GET ...
87.xx.xxx.xxx - - [20/Oct/2020:22:29:16 +0000] "GET ...
```

But thats my external ip address not the real ip4 address.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Are you accessing the service from inside `87.xx.xxx.xxx`?

Comment: no actually the nginx runs on a aws ec2 instance and I am calling the website from my pc browser. When I check my pc ip4 addres is something like 192.xxx.... and the external is 87.xx..... On acccess log of nginx I see the 87.xx... addres.

Comment: If its `192.168.x.x` its a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) that only exists on your LAN. AWS will see your **public** IP address which you can check by browsing to a website like http://www.myipaddress.com/

Comment: Yes its private. Then how can I allow some IP address on nginx cause the public IP is changing always after few days. Do you have an idea? My problem is I want only allow users who is in a specific network. e.g if they are connected via vpn.